# VSCode only shows one suggestion for snippets or emmet

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, emmet

[As you can see, it only shows a line. I can't see the other suggestions. This happens in all files, not only css files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpFma.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the suggestion box clicking on the border ;)

Comment: :O OMG I didn't know that! Thank you so much, you saved me! <3

Comment: XD np glad to help !